# Deleting a row form SQLite Database via ListView

Tags: android, android-sqlite, sqlite

I just tried to implement SQLite database thing in my Android App. Maybe I am not getting everything perfectly at Android developer Guide, So, I just found a nice tutorial on web, from this [website](http://androidexample.com/SQLite_Database_Manipulation_Class_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=51&aaid=76).

Moreover, I just understood everything I need and implementing well until the DELETION operation.

From that above mentioned website code, I have this code to delete single user:

```
// Deleting single contact
public static void deleteUserData(UserData data) {
    final SQLiteDatabase db = open();
    db.delete(USER_TABLE, KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(data.getID()) });
    db.close();
}
```

In my Application i am getting text from Edittext and retrieving it and showing it on the ListView. Also implemented "listItem.onItemLongClickListener()" to delete an item from the ListView, as shown below:

```
    @Override
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long arg3) {
    //UserData dataView = new UserData();
    //DBAdapter.deleteUserData(dataView);   

    allData.remove(position);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    return false;
}
```

**I am not able to understand how to pass the correct argument to the deleteUserData(UserData data) method.**

My problem here is **How to delete single item and set the autoincremented primary key value accordingly.**

P.S : Please refer to the above link for complete code reference in that site.

Thanks.

Comment: You want to reduce the autoincrement of primary to get reduced when you delete a data?

Comment: Excactly, But I also need to know how to delete the DATA(Single row in the above case);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get the index from position variable of click method, then get the userdata by using position like `Userdata dt = userlist[position];` from the list that you bind with listview 
then you can call your delete method like `deleteData(dt.getID())`